# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sta, apartment-state

I am using the MessageBox provided by [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessageBox). And I get the error

**The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this**

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
    MessageBox.Show("Opeartion could not be completed. Please try again.","Error",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
})).Start();
```

How can I set the ApartmentState in this case

Edit:
I am trying to display a modeless MessageBox using MessageBox control of WPF Toolkit.
So far the code I have is as follows:

```
void SomeFunction()
{
// calls to some UI, and processing and then

var th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
                                        {
                                           MessageBox.Show("Opeartion could not be completed. Please try again.",
                                                "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                                        }));

                                        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                                        th.Start();
                                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

**According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) There exists builtin modal MessageBox in WPF but if you want to use Modeless MessageBox then you have to create custom window and then show it. 
Creating, showing and and returning value from custom modeless MessageBox is not very tough.**
You can see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link

It is not wiser to use different thread for messagebox only. Anyway you can set single apartment state by following...

```
  Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Opeartion could not be completed. Please try again.", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }));

  th.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
  th.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// enable unit test to mock a dispatcher
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
if (Application.Current != null)
{
    // use the application dispatcher if running from the software
    dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
}

if (dispatcher != null)
{
    // delegate the operation to UI thread.
    dispatcher.Invoke(
        delegate
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Opeartion could not be completed. Please try again.","Error",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
        });
}
```